# Skipping every other line while importing Strings from a .txt file in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm attempting to import Strings from a .txt file with 50,000 rows.  Every single row in the txt file has exactly one string with all under-case letters and no spaces in between the letters.  The code I've written below is working, but there is one strange issue, it skips every other row of the .txt file (specifically the even-numbered rows). If any one could help me identify where I've gone wrong, it would be much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class WordRecommender {

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               String strLine = "";
               ArrayList<Word> objectArray = new ArrayList<Word>();
               try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("engDictionary.txt"));
                     while (strLine != null)
                      {
                       strLine = br.readLine();
                       sb.append(strLine);
                       sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                       strLine = br.readLine();
                       if (strLine==null)
                          break;
                       objectArray.add(new Word(strLine));
                   }
                    br.close();
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   System.err.println("File not found");
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
               }
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Word {

    String wordName;
    ArrayList<Character> uniqueLetters;

    public Word(String string) {
        ArrayList<Character> tempArray = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) { 
                        tempArray.add(string.charAt(i));
                    }

        this.wordName = string;
        this.uniqueLetters = tempArray;
}
```

Comment: rethink the need of `strLine = br.readLine();
                       if (strLine==null)
                          break;` inside the while loop you have

Comment: @Naman I've tried removing ``` if (strLine==null) break; ``` but it gives me the error message ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Word.<init>(Word.java:11)
 at WordRecommender.main(WordRecommender.java:152)```

Comment: I meant the both the statements, but yeah, it looks to me all you need though is `try (Stream<String> lines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("engDictionary.txt")).lines()) {
            List<Word> objectArray = lines
                    .map(Word::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found");
        }`

Comment: @Naman thank you for that! I dont think it every would be null I just wanted to be safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside while loop, you are reading 2 lines and appending only one. You can do this instead:

```java
while (strLine != null) {
    strLine = br.readLine();
    if (strLine==null)
        break;
    sb.append(strLine);
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    objectArray.add(new Word(strLine));
}
```